# How to validate orc vectorization is working within spark application?

Tags: apache-spark, vectorization, orc

I have enabled below listed configurations within my spark streaming 
application but I unable to infer the performance benefit  after setting these parameters ,
If any one of you know any means to validate whether vectorization is working as expeced/enabled correctly !

Note: I am using Spark 2.3 and converted all the data within my application 
in native orc format 1.4 version.

```
sparkSqlCtx.setConf("spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown", "true") 
sparkSqlCtx.setConf("spark.sql.orc.enabled", "true") 
sparkSqlCtx.setConf("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc", "true") 
sparkSqlCtx.setConf("spark.sql.orc.char.enabled", "true") 
sparkSqlCtx.setConf("spark.sql.orc.impl","native") 
sparkSqlCtx.setConf("spark.sql.orc.enableVectorizedReader","true")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set as below

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.orc.impl=native")
```

You can confirm with

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.orc.impl").show
```